# Does all applications receive BroadcastReceiver at the same time?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Today I noticed that when the network connectivity changes the first notification received will be from whatsApp. Before the notification from hangout or Skype the notification from whats app arrives. so is there a priority list of according to witch the BroadcastReceiver receives the message. I installed whatsApp before hangout and Skype gives an advantage to whatsApp that it receivers message before the other two. Or is it simply because whatsApp service is faster than the other two ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems the WhatsApp developers may have picked a higher priority for receiving messages.

Note that this is not necessarily an advantage. WhatsApp could inadvertently pick up background messages (in the case of sms messages) that were meant for other applications to pick up and delete before they were to trickle down to the lower priority broadcast receivers.

That being said, this doesn't mean that the speed and latency aren't being affected at some other point outside of the device itself. For instance, Facebook publicized the fact that it is paying some US cell phone carriers to house its own Facebook servers on premises and give them higher priority on their own cell networks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If BroadcastReceiver with Intent-filter then they all will get same event. However you can use `android:priority` to execute a particular BroadcastReceiver on priority based.

Comment: but android:priority is possible only in the case of synchronous messages. is STATE_CHANGE synchronous messages?

Comment: @billgates sorry, no Idea about it. But I use `android:priority` in reading SMS application, here my application read's incoming sms first before it lends into inbox. That's Why I know this part.

Comment: SMS, MMS, cloud 2 device messages, emails, etc, they're all asynchronous, even if they can appear in your inbox in an instant.